# Binary Classification with Rule Based approach rather than proper algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, rules, classification, bayesian

Problem Statement is somewhat like this:

> Given a website, we have to classify it into one of the two predefined classes (say whether its an e-commerce website or not?)

We have already tried Naive Bayes Algorithms for this with multiple pre-processing techniques (stop word removal, stemming etc.) and proper features.

We want to increase the accuracy to 90 or somewhat closer, which we are not getting from this approach.

The issue here is, while evaluating the accuracy manually, we look for a few identifiers on web page (e.g. Checkout button, Shop/Shopping,paypal and many more) which are sometimes missed in our algorithms.

We were thinking, if we are too sure of these identifiers, why don't we create a `rule based classifier` where we will classify a page as per a set of rules(which will be written on the basis of some priority).

e.g. if it contains shop/shopping and has checkout button then it's an ecommerce page.
And many similar rules in some priority order.

Depending on a few rules we will visit other pages of the website as well (currently, we visit only home page which is also a reason of not getting very high accuracy).

What are the potential issues that we will be facing with rule based approach? Or it would be better for our use case?

Would be a good idea to create those rules with sophisticated algorithms(e.g. `FOIL, AQ` etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***Decision Tree*** algorithm can take your data and return a *rule set* for prediction of unlabeled instances.

In fact, a decision tree is really just a *recursive descent partitioner comprised of a set of rules* in which each rule sits at a node in the tree and application of that rule on an unlabeled data instance, sends this instance down either the left fork or right fork.

Many decision tree implementations explicitly generate a rule set, but this isn't necesary, because the rules (both what the rule is and the position of that rule in the decision flow) are easy to see just by looking at the tree that represents the trained decision tree classifier.

In particular, each rule is just a Boolean test for a particular value in a particular feature (data column or field).

For instance, suppose one of the features in each data row describes the type of **Application Cache**; further suppose that this feature has three possible values, *memcache*, *redis*, and *custom*. Then a rule might be Applilcation Cache | memcache, or *does this data instance have an Application Cache based on redis?*

The rules extracted from a decision tree are **Boolean**--either true or false. By convention False is represented by the left edge (or link to the child node below and to the left-hand-side of this parent node); and True is represented by the right-hand-side edge.

Hence, a new (unlabeled) data row begins at the root node, then is sent down either the right or left side depending on whether the rule at the root node is answered True or False. The next rule is applied (at least level in the tree hierarchy) until the data instance reaches the lowest level (a node with no rule, or leaf node).

Once the data point is filtered to a leaf node, then it is in essence classified, becasue each leaf node has a distribution of training data instances associated with it (e.g., 25% Good | 75% Bad, if Good and Bad are class labels). This empirical distribution (which in the ideal case is comprised of a data instances having just one class label) determines the unknown data instances's estimated class label.

The Free & Open-Source library, ***[Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/)***, has a [decision tree module](http://orange.biolab.si/doc/widgets/_static/Classify/ClassificationTree.htm) (implementations of specific ML techniques are referred to as "widgets" in Orange) which seems to be a solid implementation of C4.5, which is probably the most widely used and perhaps the best decision tree implementation.

An O'Reilly Site has a [tutorial on decision tree construction and use](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2006/02/09/ai_decision_trees.html), including source code for a working decision tree module in **python**.

Comment: So is the only thing preventing the statement "Every rule based classifier can be represented as a decision tree" or "Rule based classifiers are equivalent to decision trees" is the fact that one can create incoherent rule sets or rule sets that have cycles, whereas by definition a decision tree is acyclic?

Answer (score 2):

```
The issue here is, while evaluating the accuracy manually, we look for a few identifiers on web page (e.g. Checkout button, Shop/Shopping,paypal and many more) which are sometimes missed in our algorithms.
```

So why don't you include this information in your classification scheme? It's not hard to find a payment/checkout button in the html, so the presence of these should definitely be features. A good classifier relies on two things- good data, and good features. Make sure you have both!

If you must do a rule based classifier, then think of it more or less like a decision tree. It's very easy to do if you are using a functional programming language- basically just recurse until you hit an endpoint, at which point you are given a classification.

Comment: Even after adding these features, sometimes it is classified as non-ecommerce because of noise or more features of non-ecommerce category.

Yeah, I agree to rule based part.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's worth taking a stab at the problem with a decision-tree based classifier. That might cut out the noise you are seeing as it introduces some dependencies between features.

Comment: And also, rules can be created in better ways and provide more info(sometimes) than feature does. Ex- We can create a rule with multiple 'and'/'or' clause but feature doesn't provide anything like this.
Correct me, If I am wrong.

Comment: you could in theory have a features 'foo_AND_bar', 'foo_OR_bar', but that's when feature selection starts getting esoteric. I worked on a system a few years ago where management decided to go with the rule-based version because although recalled sucked (typical of rule-based systems), it was very easy for the non-math people to understand, and there's a lot of value in that. In a very narrow use-case like yours, rule based should work acceptably; for bigger scenarios it gets unmanageable quickly.

Comment: Depending on your learning algorithm there's no reason why it can't account for "high X and low Y" or whatever. Decision trees have the advantage of being more human-understandable, but you might also want to try running an SVM or other algorithm that's more powerful than naive Bayes.

Comment: We always get this recommendation to use SVM, we gave it a shot which was not very successful but we did not try our best.
I will try it once, Could you please point to any good SVM library in java( I have heard of libsvm but never worked on it)?

Comment: SVM is HEAVILY dependent on kernel and parameter choice so there's lots of tuning to do. Unfortunately a lot of the machine learning packages in Java are painful- maxent using Mallet is what I would recommend but it's a total bitch to get setup unless you get Fei Xia's helper classes for Ling 572 (UW Dept of Computational Linguistics).

Comment: @nflacco I completely agree to machine learning packages thing! I will have a look at this! Thanks!